# Android: Image view size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i have set of 5 child Linear-layout which i placed in a parent linear-layout with horizontal orientation, the linear layout has weight sum of 5 and each child layout has a weight of 1,Inside each child view i have image view and text-view  and all the image view has width = match-parent & height= wrap content.

---

I wanted a layout such that no matter which size of image i used the image get's re-sized proportionately so that entire width of screen is filled and according to image width their height should be drawn

---

```
               <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvInfo"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="5" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivTodo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/to_do100" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="To Do"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivsure"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/football100" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="sure"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivTicket"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/add_ticket50" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Tickets"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivWalk"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/walking100" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Walkin"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivWeather"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/storm50" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="Weather"
                        android:textColor="@color/White" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add 'android:scaleType="fitXY"' in your imageview

Comment: i tried scale type but it doesn't work, the images with larger dimensions are pushing other image's

Comment: Try, android:layout_weight=".25"

Comment: Also, give android:layout_width="0dp" to child linear layout

Comment: i already declare weightsum=5 in parent so when child have weight =1 then all the child width should remain same, but when i load images of different size their width get's out of proportion

Comment: I have added the answer.

Comment: This is not the best way to do it. But then it worked for me. Set width and height manually for each imageview. You can set different width and height for different screensizes.

Comment: what is the best way to make n number of square which will cover the entire screen width , these square should adjust the size of the image placed in them instead of changing their size according to image

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted your TextViews, find below code to adjust imageview with equal weight

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvInfo"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5" >

            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivTodo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivsure"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivTicket"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivWalk"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivWeather"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Feel free to revert for any query.

Comment: can u try using images of different size, the images are now fitting in width but their height varies